# How to pass variables to JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, jsp, request

I am a beginner in JQuery and JSP.

**What i need is:**

I need to pass certain arguments from one JSP page to another JSP page and need to get these arguments inside the JavaScript's code in the target JSP page.

**Input:**

The arguments contain two string variable and a string array variable.Arguments are passed using the below code from the first jsp to second.

```
window.location = "StockLedgerReport.jsp?startdt=" + stDate + "&enddt=" + 
edDate+"&iditm="+itemsid;
```

Where iditm is a string array.
 I have tried to obtain these values using the below code.But i doesn't get the original value at the javascript.

```
var startd=<%=request.getParameter("startdt")%>;
var endd=<%=request.getParameter("enddt")%>;
var myarray=<%=request.getParameterValues("iditm")%>;
```

So how to obtain these arguments inside the JavaScript code of the target JSP.

Please help.

Comment: How are the two pages connected? How do you go between them?

Comment: use forms to connect pages.

Comment: have you got ur answer yet?

Comment: no.I got the values for the first two arguments.But i didn't get the values for the string array passed.I tried the below code to get that var myarray='<%=(String[])request.getParameterValues("iditm")%>'; and i got the value '[Ljava.lang.String;@74fd63'.that's not the value that i passed.How to retrieve the array values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clear solution would be to transfer the with the request URL.

Lets assume you have 2 pages (p1 and p2)

p1 will have a form with an input:

```
<form id="p1form">
    <input type="hidden" name="p1val" val="{your value}">
</form>
```

p2 will catch the requesst parameter and set it on a js var:

```
<script>
    var myvar = <%=request.getParamter('p1val')%>;
</script>
```

Another approach is to set the var on p1 using javascript:

```
<script>
      var newinput = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", 
                                                          "p1val").val("p1data");
      $('#form1').append($(newinput));
</scipr>
```

and p2 remain the same,

Good luck

Comment: I have used the code like var myvar = <%=request.getParamter('p1val')%>; .But i got some other values instead of the original value that is passed

Comment: How did you transfer the data? what type of data is it?

Comment: window.location = "StockLedgerReport.jsp?startdt=" + stDate + "&enddt=" + 
edDate+"&iditm="+itemsid; I used this code to pass the variables.Here stDate and edDate are string variables and itemsid is a string array.

Comment: where recieving itemised in p2 cast it to String[]. that should work from what you showing

Comment: i got the value for the first two variables at javascript side.But i didn't get the value for the array string.I used the code var myarray='<%=(String[])request.getParameterValues("iditm")%>'; ,then i print the value of myarray using alert and i got the value as '[Ljava.lang.String;@74fd63'.How to get the values of 'myarray' correctly?

Comment: -do you any idea to get the array values??

Comment: You cant cast it to a javascript array. it wont work.
What you need to do is take the Array in the java code in p2 and loop over it, for each iterate set the var into the javascript array. same as you did for the others

Comment: what do you mean by 'p2'?

Comment: then how to do the above case using iteration?

Comment: i mean how to set the var into the javascript array foreach iteration over the array elements ?

Comment: <%
String[] items = (String[]) request.getParameterValues("iditm");
for (String s: items) {
      %>
        <script>items[] = <%=s></script>
<%}%>

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using forms in the first jsp page

Try this

1.jsp

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" name="textbox2">
```

2.jsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="textbox3"id="textbox3" value="<%=request.getParamter('textbox1')%>">
<input type="hidden" name="textbox4" id="textbox4"value="<%=request.getParamter('textbox2')%>">
```

then you could get this value in your javascript using

```
document.getElementbyId('textbox3').value;
document.getElementbyId('textbox4').value
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This `<%=request.getParamter('textbox1')%>` could be used directly in js module which is called on load of the target form. hidden variables are not required